# ajax not returning complete json in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am using a code to get json from a url using ajax which is returning half of json object not full object

```
function getsubcategoriesValues(){ 
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log(this.responseText);
            var subcat = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log(subcat);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "http://majlis247.com:81/api/service/1", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

only returns

> "Id":1,"Name":"Air Conditioning","Description":"Air Conditioning","IsFeatured":true,"IconPath":"AirConditions.svg","ImagePath":"18fc5e7d-94d4-413a-a538-ed5d0a00f699_d3dabdde-6f9c-4c2d-98ad-439e30b16cec_Air-Conditioning.jpg","RegisterCompanyCount":0}

this in console. where is the remaining data lost? how can i get that?

Comment: Check the network tab in dev tools to see what's coming back from the server. We can't know.

Comment: your specified link return this;
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "Air Conditioning",
  "Description": "Air Conditioning",
  "IsFeatured": true,
  "IconPath": "AirConditions.svg",
  "ImagePath": "18fc5e7d-94d4-413a-a538-ed5d0a00f699_d3dabdde-6f9c-4c2d-98ad-439e30b16cec_Air-Conditioning.jpg",
  "RegisterCompanyCount": 0
}

Comment: check at the server side this will be all data the server return.

Comment: Server issue. Your server is not returning the `SubServices` node.

Comment: interestingly if you visit that URL in Chrome, it will default to returning XML (instead of JSON) which _does_ return the SubServices node. Based on that behaviour, I suspect it's probably a .NET WebAPI service, so there's probably some settings in the serializer which is telling it not to return some of the nodes when the format is JSON. Unless there are some options you can send in the request which would affect this, then I think it's an issue at the server side which you would have to talk to the provider about.

Comment: `in console` - console logs tend to get truncated. If you get an error trying to parse the JSON, then, yes, the value coming from the server is "short", if JSON.parse succeeds, then there is no issue at all ... the console is a debugging tool, so don't always rely on what you see there especially with **long** text

Answer (score -1):

Run your browser by disable your security

chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security

Comment: sorry I dont have any such access because I am creating web view application.  is there any way to handle it through front end(javascript) code??

Comment: can you explain how this is relevant?